# Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes

Tags: jsf, primefaces, process, updates

What exactly are `process` and `update` in PrimeFaces `p:commandXxx` components and `execute` and `render` in `f:ajax` tag?

Which works at the time of validation? What does `update` attribute do rather than updating value to component from back end? Do `process` attribute bind value to model? What exactly do `@this`, `@parent`, `@all` and `@form` in both attributes?

The example below is working fine, but I am a little confused in basic concepts.

```html
<p:commandButton process="@parent"
                 update="@form"
                 action="#{bean.submit}" 
                 value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 351, accepted):

### `<p:commandXxx process>` `<p:ajax process>` `<f:ajax execute>`

The `process` attribute is server side and can only affect [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html)s implementing [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) (input fields) or [`ActionSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) (command fields). The `process` attribute tells JSF, using a space-separated list of client IDs, which components exactly must be processed through the entire JSF lifecycle upon (partial) form submit.

JSF will then apply the request values (finding HTTP request parameter based on component's own client ID and then either setting it as submitted value in case of `EditableValueHolder` components or queueing a new [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/ActionEvent.html) in case of `ActionSource` components), perform conversion, validation and updating the model values (`EditableValueHolder` components only) and finally invoke the queued `ActionEvent` (`ActionSource` components only). JSF will skip processing of all other components which are not covered by `process` attribute. Also, components whose `rendered` attribute evaluates to `false` during apply request values phase will also be skipped as part of safeguard against tampered requests.

Note that it's in case of `ActionSource` components (such as `<p:commandButton>`) very important that you also include the component itself in the `process` attribute, particularly if you intend to invoke the action associated with the component. So the below example which intends to process only certain input component(s) when a certain command component is invoked ain't gonna work:

```
<p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
<p:commandButton process="foo" action="#{bean.action}" />
```

It would only process the `#{bean.foo}` and **not** the `#{bean.action}`. You'd need to include the command component itself as well:

```
<p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
<p:commandButton process="@this foo" action="#{bean.action}" />
```

Or, as you apparently found out, using `@parent` if they happen to be the only components having a common parent:

```
<p:panel><!-- Type doesn't matter, as long as it's a common parent. -->
    <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <p:commandButton process="@parent" action="#{bean.action}" />
</p:panel>
```

Or, if they both happen to be the only components of the parent [`UIForm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html) component, then you can also use `@form`:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <p:commandButton process="@form" action="#{bean.action}" />
</h:form>
```

This is sometimes undesirable if the form contains more input components which you'd like to skip in processing, more than often in cases when you'd like to update another input component(s) or some UI section based on the current input component in an ajax listener method. You namely don't want that validation errors on other input components are preventing the ajax listener method from being executed.

Then there's the `@all`. This has no special effect in `process` attribute, but only in `update` attribute. A `process="@all"` behaves exactly the same as `process="@form"`. HTML doesn't support submitting multiple forms at once anyway.

There's by the way also a `@none` which may be useful in case you absolutely don't need to process anything, but *only* want to update some specific parts via `update`, particularly those sections whose content doesn't depend on submitted values or action listeners.

Noted should be that the `process` attribute has **no** influence on the HTTP request payload (the amount of request parameters). Meaning, the default HTML behavior of sending "everything" contained within the HTML representation of the `<h:form>` will be not be affected. In case you have a large form, and want to reduce the HTTP request payload to only these absolutely necessary in processing, i.e. only these covered by `process` attribute, then you can set the `partialSubmit` attribute in PrimeFaces Ajax components as in `<p:commandXxx ... partialSubmit="true">` or `<p:ajax ... partialSubmit="true">`. You can also configure this 'globally' by editing `web.xml` and add

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
    <param-value>partial</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`<o:form>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form) of OmniFaces 3.0+ which defaults to this behavior.

The standard JSF equivalent to the PrimeFaces specific `process` is `execute` from `<f:ajax execute>`. It behaves exactly the same except that it doesn't support a comma-separated string while the PrimeFaces one does (although I personally recommend to just stick to space-separated convention), nor the `@parent` keyword. Also, it may be useful to know that `<p:commandXxx process>` defaults to `@form` while `<p:ajax process>` and `<f:ajax execute>` defaults to `@this`. Finally, it's also useful to know that `process` supports the so-called "PrimeFaces Selectors", see also [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

---

### `<p:commandXxx update>` `<p:ajax update>` `<f:ajax render>`

The `update` attribute is client side and can affect the HTML representation of all `UIComponent`s. The `update` attribute tells JavaScript (the one responsible for handling the ajax request/response), using a space-separated list of client IDs, which parts in the HTML DOM tree need to be updated as response to the form submit.

JSF will then prepare the right ajax response for that, containing *only* the requested parts to update. JSF will skip all other components which are not covered by `update` attribute in the ajax response, hereby keeping the response payload small. Also, components whose `rendered` attribute evaluates to `false` during render response phase will be skipped. Note that even though it would return `true`, JavaScript cannot update it in the HTML DOM tree if it was initially `false`. You'd need to wrap it or update its parent instead. See also [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014).

Usually, you'd like to update *only* the components which *really* need to be "refreshed" in the client side upon (partial) form submit. The example below updates the entire parent form via `@form`:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true" />
    <p:message id="foo_m" for="foo" />
    <p:inputText id="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" required="true" />
    <p:message id="bar_m" for="bar" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update="@form" />
</h:form>
```

*(note that `process` attribute is omitted as that defaults to `@form` already)*

Whilst that may work fine, the update of input and command components is in this particular example unnecessary. Unless you change the model values `foo` and `bar` inside `action` method (which would in turn be unintuitive in UX perspective), there's no point of updating them. The message components are the only which *really* need to be updated:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true" />
    <p:message id="foo_m" for="foo" />
    <p:inputText id="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" required="true" />
    <p:message id="bar_m" for="bar" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update="foo_m bar_m" />
</h:form>
```

However, that gets tedious when you have many of them. That's one of the reasons why PrimeFaces Selectors exist. Those message components have in the generated HTML output a common style class of `ui-message`, so the following should also do:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true" />
    <p:message id="foo_m" for="foo" />
    <p:inputText id="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" required="true" />
    <p:message id="bar_m" for="bar" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update="@(.ui-message)" />
</h:form>
```

*(note that you should keep the IDs on message components, otherwise `@(...)` won't work! Again, see [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work) for detail)*

The `@parent` updates only the parent component, which thus covers the current component and all siblings and their children. This is more useful if you have separated the form in sane groups with each its own responsibility. The `@this` updates, obviously, only the current component. Normally, this is only necessary when you need to change one of the component's own HTML attributes in the action method. E.g.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update="@this" 
    oncomplete="doSomething('#{bean.value}')" />
```

Imagine that the `oncomplete` needs to work with the `value` which is changed in `action`, then this construct wouldn't have worked if the component isn't updated, for the simple reason that `oncomplete` is part of generated HTML output (and thus all EL expressions in there are evaluated during render response).

The `@all` updates the entire document, which should be used with care. Normally, you'd like to use a true GET request for this instead by either a plain link (`<a>` or `<h:link>`) or a redirect-after-POST by `?faces-redirect=true` or `ExternalContext#redirect()`. In effects, `process="@form" update="@all"` has exactly the same effect as a non-ajax (non-partial) submit. In my entire JSF career, the only sensible use case I encountered for `@all` is to display an error page in its entirety in case an exception occurs during an ajax request. See also [What is the correct way to deal with JSF 2.0 exceptions for AJAXified components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components/)

The standard JSF equivalent to the PrimeFaces specific `update` is `render` from `<f:ajax render>`. It behaves exactly the same except that it doesn't support a comma-separated string while the PrimeFaces one does (although I personally recommend to just stick to space-separated convention), nor the `@parent` keyword. Both `update` and `render` defaults to `@none` (which is, "nothing").

---

**See also:**

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156)
- [Execution order of events when pressing PrimeFaces p:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146630)
- [How to decrease request payload of p:ajax during e.g. p:dataTable pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934671)
- [How to show details of current row from p:dataTable in a p:dialog and update after save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236228)
- [How to use <h:form> in JSF page? Single form? Multiple forms? Nested forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903)

Comment: When I use update="" then the managed property of the backing bean does not get set and my @PostConstruct routine fails. Any thoughts? EDIT:•If you rely a managed property of #{param} being present in the subsequent POST requests, then you need to include it as <f:param> in the UICommand components.

Comment: may a process/update of a panelGroup will process/update the contents of this panelGroup ex : <h:panelGroup id="pgId">//input texts goes here<h:panelGroup><p:commandLink process="pgId" update="pgId"/>

Comment: @BalusC You said we need to indicate `@this` in case of `ActionSource` so the action be called, although if I look into Primefaces showcase in [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) `process="@this"` is not set and it works well, why that?

Comment: @Rapster: because `process` is not set, so it uses default value of `@form`. This is also explained in above answer.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks again! I met a problem related to this, with RemoteCommand. You said default value is `@form`for `<p:commandXXX />` How can I verify that in the code? I'd like to verify this default value for RemoteCommand

Comment: i'm a bit confused, since update calls my @postconstruct init() , should i use `?faces-redirect=true` (it will be a redirect) or should i just use action  (forward) and add `update :datalist` ?

Comment: @BalusC without `process="@form"` I'm getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Content Type.` at `com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:283)`. So I had expand all my `p:commandButton` with this. PF 6.2 (Community).

Comment: @Roland: it's hiding a different, more serious, problem with the app config.

Comment: @BalusC okay, then should I avoid this then and better fix the root cause (which I don't know at my cause)?

Comment: @BalusC A noteworthy addition might be to state that limiting elements from process does not limit the amouth of elements that are included in the form submit. The whole form, with all its EditableValueHolders, is submitted but just not evaluated in the backend. At least in primefaces.

Comment: @mojoo-de: This was already linked in 3rd "See also" list. I have at least added a paragrahp on this.

Comment: I needed the `ajax="true"` flag in my command buttons for this to work how I expected.

Comment: @user4757074: That's the default already. It's more likely that you previously used `ajax="false"` without really understanding it. Just removing that attribute altogether, exactly as demonstrated in the minimal code snippets in above answer, would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 64):

If you have a hard time remembering the default values (I know I have...) here's a short extract from BalusC's answer:

| Component | Submit | Refresh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f:ajax | execute="@this" | render="@none" |
| p:ajax | process="@this" | update="@none" |
| p:commandXXX | process="@form" | update="@none" |

Comment: Just a minor correction: the default value of `process` for `p:commandXXX` is `@all`. Plus, this seems to apply for every component supporting AJAX, such as `p:menuitem`.

Comment: Hi @StephanRauh, thanks a lot for comment. Where did you read the default is `@all`? As far as I can read from BalusC's answer it is `@form`, however `@all` is equivalent to `@form` in process. Good point about the other components, I guess I will have to look in the source code when time to see what components it applies to, as I would rather not write something that may be wrong

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Thomas Andraschko told me about the `@all` bit. He must know, he's re-implemented the AJAX engine of PrimeFaces recently. Later, I double checked it but reading the source code of PrimeFaces and by looking at the XHR requests. I hope I've got it right this time because I've implemented the AJAX requests of BootsFaces to work identically to the AJAX requests of PrimeFaces.

Comment: It would be misleading to say, that the default is @all when HTML doesn't support the submit of multiple forms. Developers need to know the effective default value (so Thomas might change it accordingly). By the way, these defaults are are incorrectly defined as null in the Primefaces User Guide 6.2.

Answer (score 30):

By process (in the JSF specification it's called execute) you tell JSF to limit the processing to component that are specified every thing else is just ignored.

update indicates which element will be updated when the server respond back to you request.

**@all** : Every component is processed/rendered.

**@this**: The requesting component with the execute attribute is processed/rendered.

**@form** : The form that contains the requesting component is processed/rendered.

**@parent**: The parent that contains the requesting component is processed/rendered.

With Primefaces you can even use JQuery selectors, check out this blog: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867

Answer (score 11):

### JSF 2.0+ keywords

- `@this` Current component.
- `@all` Whole view.
- `@form` Closest ancestor form of current component.
- `@none` No component.

### JSF 2.3+ keywords

- `@child(n)` nth child.
- `@composite` Closest composite component ancestor.
- `@id(id)` Used to search components by their id ignoring the component tree structure and naming containers.
- `@namingcontainer` Closest ancestor naming container of current component.
- `@parent` Parent of the current component.
- `@previous` Previous sibling.
- `@next` Next sibling.
- `@root` UIViewRoot instance of the view, can be used to start searching from the root instead the current component.

### PrimeFaces specific keywords

- `@row(n)` nth row.
- `@widgetVar(name)` Component with given widgetVar.

And you can even use something called "PrimeFaces Selectors" which allows you to use jQuery Selector API. For example to process all inputs in a element with the CSS class `myClass`:

```
process="@(.myClass :input)"
```

See:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/searchexpression

### PrimeFaces 10+ Observer / Event

This allows you to update components based on a custom event name, set by the `@obs(event)` keyword. For example:

```html
<p:commandButton update="@obs(myEvent)"/>

<h:panelGroup>
    <p:autoUpdate on="myEvent"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

See:

- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/observer.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

These are PrimeFaces features to provide partial view processing and partial rendering. You can control what to execute in lifecycle and what to render with ajax.

When using backing bean properties in expression language

- process attribute calls SETTER methods
- update attribute calls GETTER methods

[primefaces forum](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=53595&sid=2ba00132ff3e5da2ae99263bbb7378a5#p53595)